# Why can I access a service through Postman but not through Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-services

I have a service running in a port X locally. I can call this service successfully using Postman, but when I try to use a local Windows Forms application using `HttpClient.SendAsync()` I get the following error:

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:443
```

What gives? I've tried the following solutions that I found online:

- tried to see if there was another process listening in that port, but `netstat -o` returned nothing
- tried checking if there weren't any shared internet connections, but there were none. I disabled the option anyway
- tried restarting IIS

Any ideas why I can't hit this endpoint from a local application but can from Postman?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

END POINT ADDRESS?

Did you add it in Service Reference?

Check your App.config File.

It looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WebService1Soap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:7801/webservicesample/WebService1.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebService1Soap"
                contract="ServiceReference1.WebService1Soap" name="WebService1Soap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

It just something like that.